# Error in plm random effects Swamy–Arora (swar) estimator with lagged dependent

Tags: r, plm

I am using synthetic data with a model that has a lagged dependent variable. When estimating a random effects model using Swamy–Arora estimator (default) with package plm, I get the error

```
Error in swar(object, data, effect) : 
  the estimated variance of the individual effect is negative
```

But, if I try with any other of the available estimators (namely, "walhus", "amemiya", "nerlove" or  "kinla"), then everything works fine.

Below is a code that shows the issue.

```
###########################################################
# Script to show problem with swar estimator of r.e. in plm
# Date: 20151013
###########################################################

# Dependencies
library(MASS) # to sample correlated multinormal
library(plm)

#########################################################################
# CREATE TEST DATA
# This part creates a panel with H individuals and S observations each
# The model has a lagged dependent variable with weight rho
# We also use k multinormal correlated (r) predictors, with weights = 1:k
# We use random effects u = 1:H
# Series start at y0
#########################################################################

k = 5
r = 0.5
S = 1000
R = mat.or.vec(k, k) + r
diag(R) = 1
y0 = 1
rho = 0.9
sigma_e = 3
H = 10

for(h in 1:H){
  # Predictors
  X = mvrnorm(S, rep(0, k), R)

  # Dependent
  y = mat.or.vec(S, 1)
  y[1] = y0
  eps = rnorm(S, 0, sigma_e)

  for(i in 2:S){
    y[i] = rho * y[i-1] + as.numeric(X[i,] %*% 1:k) + eps[i] + h
  }

  # we create a lagged depedendent variable manually to see if this fixes
  # the problem
  temp = data.frame(y[2:S], y[1:(S-1)], X[2:S, ], rep(h, S-1))
  names(temp) = c("y", "y.l", paste("x", 1:5, sep=""), "id")
  temp$t = 1:(S-1)

  if (h == 1) {
    datos = temp
  } else {
    datos = rbind(datos, temp)
  }
}

# Finished

######################################################################
# ESTIMATE THE PANEL
# First we estimate F.E.: it work perfectly
# Then we estimate R.E.
######################################################################

pdatos = pdata.frame(datos, index = c("id", "t"))

# Fixed effects
fitfe = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = pdatos)
summary(fitfe) # Beta OK
sqrt(sum(fitfe$residuals ^ 2) / fitfe$df.residual) # sigma_e OK
summary(fixef(fitfe)) # F.E. OK

# Random effects: swar
fitre = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
            data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "swar") # Fails

# manually created lag
fitre = plm(y ~ y.l + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
          data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "swar") # Fails

# Random effects: other methods
fitre = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
            data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "walhus") # OK
summary(fitre)
fitre = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
            data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "amemiya") # OK
summary(fitre)
fitre = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
            data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "nerlove") # OK
summary(fitre)
fitre = plm(y ~ lag(y, 1) + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
            data = pdatos, model = "random", random.method = "kinla") # OK
summary(fitre)

# End
```

Comment: You do know that estimating model with lagged dependent variable gives biased with random effects will give you a biased estimates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is correct; this is not an error with the `plm` package in particular. The default Swamy and Arora (1972) estimator (`random.method="swar"` is used if not something else is explicitly stated by the user) is not guaranteed to yield positive estimates for the variance.

> Wooldridge (2010), p. 296 has some advice:
>
> „As a practical matter, equation (10.37) is not guaranteed to be
> positive, although it is in the vast majority of applications. A
> negative value for sigma_c^2 is indicative of negative serial
> correlation in u_it, probably a substantial amount, which means that
> Assumption RE.3a is violated. Alternatively, some other assumption in
> the model can be false. We should make sure that time dummies are
> included in the model if aggregate effects are important; omitting
> them can induce serial correlation in the implied u_it. When the
> intercepts are allowed to change freely over time, the effects of
> other aggregate variables will not be identified. If sigma_c^2 is
> negative, unrestricted FGLS may be called for; see Section 10.4.3."

Sometimes, just adding more control variables or transforming variables also help to overcome this issue (from a technical viewpoint) if you want to stick with the swar estimator.

Comment: Good answer, but it should be noted, that random effects model should not be used for regression with lagged dependent variable.