# OLS model and random effects model generate identical outcomes

Tags: mixed-model, least-squares, panel-data

Using R (package `plm`), I ran OLS and random effects model to compare the effect of marriage on earnings based on the youth survey longitudinal data.
Strangely, both models produce identical results as shown below although they were supposed to be different. I want to know what kind of mistake I made in my regression.

The data sample is provided below and variables of interest are EARNINGS: wage level,  MARRIED: 1 if you are married.  SOONMARR: 1 if you will be married within 4 month.  EXP: experience.  AGE: age.

```
structure(list(TIME = c(18, 18, 10, 1, 9, 0, 2, 11, 3, 8, 6, 
4, 2, 4, 10, 7, 18, 5, 7, 16, 18, 14, 0, 2, 13, 6, 16, 8, 18, 
14), ID = c(2270, 2963, 11990, 1620, 2176, 3493, 5609, 2537, 
1452, 1091, 4245, 2197, 4731, 3050, 914, 5085, 2310, 2514, 12127, 
3269, 1692, 5570, 3602, 2203, 3171, 2798, 881, 5580, 886, 4034
), MALE = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), AGE = c(38, 35, 32, 23, 
27, 22, 19, 32, 18, 30, 24, 20, 22, 24, 28, 24, 34, 25, 27, 37, 
36, 32, 23, 20, 30, 25, 35, 24, 37, 33), S = c(12, 16, 18, 16, 
12, 12, 9, 12, 8, 10, 14, 12, 11, 8, 12, 12, 13, 17, 12, 14, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 12, 16, 11, 18, 12), ETHBLACK = c(1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ETHHISP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    HEIGHT85 = c(62, 72, 71, 75, 65, 70, 62, 70, 68, 71, 68, 
    70, 72, 66, 68, 67, 67, 67, 70, 64, 65, 66, 72, 63, 69, 68, 
    70, 67, 67, 65), WEIGHT = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, 
    TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), ASVAB02 = c(40, 54, 66, 65, 43, 58, 34, 51, 
    34, 43, 46, 38, 46, 32, 54, 36, 45, 64, 38, 47, 32, 47, 53, 
    49, 66, 38, 59, 42, 57, 53), ASVAB03 = c(35, 55, 57, 56, 
    56, 56, 35, 48, 29, 59, 54, 26, 44, 41, 61, 39, 37, 55, 42, 
    46, 38, 56, 60, 47, 61, 25, 59, 47, 61, 50), ASVAB04 = c(44, 
    56, 59, 50, 56, 53, 38, 35, 35, 56, 59, 32, 29, 32, 53, 41, 
    41, 56, 41, 56, 32, 44, 56, 35, 59, 32, 59, 47, 59, 62), 
    ASVABC = c(39.75, 54.75, 62, 59, 49.5, 56.25, 35.25, 46.25, 
    33, 50.25, 51.25, 33.5, 41.25, 34.25, 55.5, 38, 42, 59.75, 
    39.75, 49, 33.5, 48.5, 55.5, 45, 63, 33.25, 59, 44.5, 58.5, 
    54.5), SM = c(12, 16, 16, 12, 12, 10, 12, 12, 6, 8, 16, 12, 
    12, 11, 10, 12, 6, 13, 11, 9, 6, 12, 11, 12, 16, 12, 16, 
    10, 14, 12), SF = c(12, 16, 18, 12, 12, 10, 8, 12, 6, 5, 
    14, NA, 10, 8, 12, 10, 6, 12, 13, 12, 6, 12, 12, 9, 20, 4, 
    16, 12, 16, 12), SIBLINGS = c(3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 
    8, 2, 2, 5, 5, 10, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 
    5, 5), YOUNGCH = c(8, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 1, 
    NA, 0, 3, NA, 6, NA, 1, 3, 10, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    1, 1, 19), MARRIED = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), SINGBOTH = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SOONMARR = c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0), SINGLE = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), URBAN = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), REGNE = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), REGNC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), REGW = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    REGS = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), EARNINGS = c(9.6738920211792, 
    40.1009712219238, 21.6322746276855, 21.5759124755859, 12.1217908859253, 
    11.6342115402222, 5.44678783416748, 8.1214771270752, 19.7070159912109, 
    7.95773506164551, 17.3935699462891, 5.66289854049683, 8.94249057769775, 
    7.5505313873291, 16.9024639129639, 8.41127777099609, 11.7915649414062, 
    7.29089403152466, 6.21522903442383, 12.5000009536743, 12.5134973526001, 
    10.3223705291748, 14.071496963501, 10.4383211135864, 81.1970825195312, 
    5.08207225799561, 23.0700016021729, 10.5174722671509, 34.5468864440918, 
    11.6457509994507), HOURS = c(40, 60, 40, 40, 40, 45, 40, 
    40, 40, 40, 45, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 40, 40, 38, 40, 45, 40, 
    56, 37, 45, 40, 50, 40, 30, 43), TENURE = c(20.9423084259033, 
    1.88461542129517, 4.4038462638855, 1.25, 6.8461537361145, 
    2.17307686805725, 0.134615391492844, 7.73076915740967, 1.36538457870483, 
    2.19230771064758, 2.57692313194275, 0.192307695746422, 2.69230771064758, 
    0.0384615398943424, 9.057692527771, 3.75, 10.4615383148193, 
    0.961538434028625, 0.15384615957737, 0.115384615957737, 5.38461542129517, 
    1.19230771064758, 2.28846144676208, 0.0384615398943424, 6.63461542129517, 
    7.28846168518066, 6.46153831481934, 5.17307710647583, 12.9038457870483, 
    15.3269233703613), EXP = c(19.0961532592773, 14.865385055542, 
    10.557692527771, 0.596153855323792, 10.3461542129517, 0.923076927661896, 
    1.28846156597137, 11.9230766296387, 1.98076927661896, 9.46153831481934, 
    4.5961537361145, 5.13461542129517, 2.8461537361145, 3.76923084259033, 
    11.1538457870483, 3.75, 15.0384616851807, 4.5, 3.67307686805725, 
    13.134614944458, 12.6730766296387, 11.7307691574097, 1.05769228935242, 
    2.82692313194275, 8.36538505554199, 6.98076915740967, 15.5961542129517, 
    5.73076915740967, 16.769229888916, 15.6730766296387), CLASSPRI = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA), CLASSGOV = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA), CLASSSE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA), UNION = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
    NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
    NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE), UNCOLB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(38964L, 
39248L, 25935L, 1581L, 21391L, 667L, 4611L, 27087L, 5260L, 18133L, 
13882L, 7758L, 4298L, 8117L, 23682L, 17143L, 38979L, 10386L, 
17642L, 36875L, 38716L, 35385L, 699L, 3426L, 32699L, 13188L, 
35869L, 20198L, 38418L, 35003L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
library(plm)
ols_pooled <- lm(log(EARNINGS) ~ MARRIED + SOONMARR + EXP + I(EXP^2) + AGE + I(AGE^2), data = df)

rem1 <- plm(log(EARNINGS) ~ MARRIED + SOONMARR + EXP + I(EXP^2) + AGE + I(AGE^2), 
            data = df, model = "random")

===============================================================
                                Dependent variable:            
                    -------------------------------------------
                                   log(EARNINGS)               
                                 OLS                  panel    
                                                     linear    
                                 (1)                   (2)     
---------------------------------------------------------------
MARRIED                       0.063***              0.063***   
                               (0.005)               (0.005)   
                                                               
SOONMARR                      0.058***              0.058***   
                               (0.007)               (0.007)   
                                                                                                                              
EXP                           0.024***              0.024***   
                               (0.003)               (0.003)   
                                                               
I(EXP2)                       0.0005***             0.0005***  
                              (0.0002)              (0.0002)   
                                                               
AGE                           0.056***              0.056***   
                               (0.006)               (0.006)   
                                                               
I(AGE2)                       -0.001***             -0.001***  
                              (0.0001)              (0.0001)   
                                                               
Constant                       0.138*                0.138*    
                               (0.082)               (0.082)   
                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   36,472                36,472    
R2                              0.324                 0.324    
Adjusted R2                     0.324                 0.324    
Residual Std. Error      0.400 (df = 36461)                    
F Statistic         1,746.272*** (df = 10; 36461) 17,462.720***
===============================================================
Note:                               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: Please describe your data, the variables and the goal of your analysis as the background necessary to understand the summary output. Also, can you provide a sample of the data? The `plm` package requires the data to be in a specific format.

Comment: @dipetkov I just modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your data and code is not reproducible/does not reproduce the table.
I get different results for the OLS and RE model with your data and `plm` commands.

In general, quite a few RE estimation techniques are not guaranteed to estimate non-negative variance components. All software packages I know set negative variance estimations to zero, effectively estimating an pooled model (the RE model degenerates to the pooled model).

You can check the variance components estimation with `plm::ercomp` for RE models estimated by `plm`, i.e., `ercomp(rem1)` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a little more details like your data and R commands? I don't exactly see how the RE degenerates to Pooled OLS with relation to non-negative variance components.

Comment: Well, from what you write, it sounds like you have an example on your side already. 

See for a quote/reference from the literature this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181444/94889, see for an artifical data and estimation example the question to this answer (where the first fitted `fitre` model has a variance set to 0, thus giving the sames results as a pooled model)